# Input Accessory View disappear after Image Picker is cancelled [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, inputaccessoryview

I have a pretty standard `inputAccessoryView` with image and album buttons. But I found that if album is launched when keyboard is shown (in other words, `textView` is the first responder), `inputAccessoryView` disappears when photo album is dismissed. How to make it stay at the bottom of the screen?

My implementation is generic:

```
let inputContainerView: UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40)

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return inputContainerView
}

lazy var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    return picker
}()

// The function that is hooked up to the album button
func handleAlbum() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is a gif demonstrating the problem. Notice the `inputAccessoryView` disappeared at the end. Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It turns out I need to ask textView to `resignFirstResponder()` before presenting the image picker. Also, add the following code. It handles the case when user cancelled the pick operation.

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Per Apple documentation:

> Your delegate’s implementation of this method should dismiss the picker view by calling the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method of the parent view controller.
>
> Implementation of this method is optional, but expected.

The `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method is deprecated and should use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding self.inputAccessoryView.becomeFirstResponder() after image picker is dismissed.